# C#: Past html code in html body mail from ssrs report

Tags: c#, html, email, reporting-services

```
Dim getHTMLTask As Task(Of Byte()) = 
Application.HubProxy.Invoke(Of Byte())("RenderReportFromSqlReports", "HTML4.0", "AllocationMail", parameters)

Dim HTMLBytes As Byte() = getHTMLTask.Result
Body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(HTMLBytes, 0, HTMLBytes.Length)

OutlookMailHelper.CreateOutlookEmail("email@email.com", "Test", body,"")
```

Hi all,

I'm trying to create a report in ssrs that I want to mail to customers.
I can get the html code in the html body of the mail but when I display the mail, the whole mail is resized. It looks very small...

I tested it with Outlook and it looks messed up but when I direct send it from outlook to gmail everything looks good...

Problem is 99% of our customers use outlook...

Comment: Where does the HTML come from?

Comment: From my ssrs report I export it to HTML4.0 and then insert that code in the mail.

Comment: You can't get any old HTML and expect it to look good when rendered by a mail client. There aren't any universal standards for rendering HTML emails like there are with HTML and web browsers. Outlook, for example uses the Microsoft Word engine. I would rethink your approach entirely.

Comment: But how I just want my text of the report in my mail.. Because I can use report translations etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure the option to allow scripts in the email client is turned on. The rendering script resizes the images and other layout nuances. If scripts are blocked in outlook then you will have to resize the images yourself or better yet, use static sized images :(